# AlertDialog в OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

Создаю небольшое меню для проекта. Обрабатываю нажатие двух кнопок - начать и продолжить. При нажатии на кнопку "Начать" хочу вызывать диалоговое окно с кнопками "Да" и "Нет". При нажатии на кнопку "Да" переходить на следующую активити. Но при нажатии кнопки не появляется диалоговое окно и ошибка:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' 
on a null object reference
```

Код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        Button resumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resumeButton);
        Button settingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        Button instructionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.instructionButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = null;

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.startButton:
                AlertDialog.Builder alterDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);
                Button buttonYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
                Button buttonNo = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonNo);

                buttonYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        final String ACTION_NEW = "NEW";

                        final String ACTION_STATUS = "STATUS";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inventory.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ACTION_STATUS, ACTION_NEW);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                alterDialog.setView(dialogView);
                AlertDialog dialog = alterDialog.create();
                dialog.show();

                break;
            case R.id.resumeButton:
                break;
            case R.id.settingsButton:
                break;
            case R.id.instructionButton:

                break;


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке,  `(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYes)` или `(Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton)` вернул null, и вы от null пытаетесь вызвать метод.

Вообще делается это немного проще:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
        if(wich == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE){
            //идем на другую активити
        } else{
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}
Dialog dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Заголовок")
                .setMessage("Основной текст")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("Отменить", listener).
                build();
dialog.show();
```

Если, конечно, вы не хотите делать свой дизайн диалога

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Требовалось написать `Button buttonYes = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);`  и тогда не возвращает null.

Comment: AlertDialog появляется, но при нажатии кнопки опять та же ошибка.

Comment: Значит проблема в том, что указали внутри слушателя. Ставьте туда брэкпоинт и смотрите где именно вылетает и какие поля что содежрат